# Converting c# code to VB.NET error

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried converting my c# code below to VB and I got 
Events cannot be declared with a delegate type that has a return type

in C#

```
internal static event GenericDelegate<Boolean, Boolean> SecurityAlertDialogWillBeShown;
    internal static event GenericDelegate<String, String, Boolean> ConnectToDialogWillBeShown;
```

`In vb.net

```
Friend Shared Event SecurityAlertDialogWillBeShown As GenericDelegate(Of [Boolean], [Boolean])
    Friend Shared Event ConnectToDialogWillBeShown As GenericDelegate(Of [String], [String], [Boolean])
```

any idea appreciated.

Comment: What is `GenericDelegate`? Please show its definition.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net, you can't create an `Event` with a delegate type that has a return type (well, the error message already told you that).

You have to declare your delegate (`GenericDelegate`) as `Sub` instead of `Function`.

Comment: Unfortunatley, this wasn't declared as a function but more like a #region call

Comment: Here is the full code http://www.cs.utah.edu/~thanhhoa/projects/LabelEx/Label%20Extraction%20(LabelEx)/WindowsInterop.cs

Comment: *wasn't declared as a function but more like a #region call* What does that mean? A delegate is declared as a delegate; and a #region can't be called, since it's not code. Somewhere in your code you declare `GenericDelegate`, and in order to use it as delegate type of an `Event`, it has to be a `Sub`, not a `Function`.